# Why DRF giving me 404

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am keep getting 404 in DRF whenever I send request from postman even though the url is correct.

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('backend.urls'))
]
```

**backend/urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('/post', views.PostView, basename='post')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

From postman I am sending post request on the endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/post but I am keep getting 404 not found error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: didn't you forget to add your app into settings.py?

Comment: I don't think you need the beginning '/' in prefix - so perhaps 'post' instead of '/post'?

Comment: I removed the '/' its still giving 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me.

- Create a app named `backend` using `python manage.py startapp {app_name}` where app_name is `backend`
- Add the newly created app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project settings.py
- In your project url.py file do this:

  ```
         from django.contrib import admin
         from django.urls import include, path
         urlpatterns = [
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            path("", include("backend.urls")),
         ]
  ```
- In your app urls.py file. (where app is backend):

  ```
      from django.urls import include, path
      from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

      from . import views

      router = DefaultRouter()
      router.register('post', views.PostView, basename='post')

      app_name = 'backend'

      urlpatterns = [
          path('', include(router.urls)),
      ]
  ```
- Then in your app(backend) views.py define `PostView`

This should work.The endpoint should be at :
`http://localhost:8000/post/` .

if your using port 8000

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `backend/urls.py`:

```py
import views
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('post', views.PostView, basename='post')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: I tried it, its still giving 404 error.